# jquery - How to trim an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wanting to know how to trim an image instead of text in jquery. The only way I know how to trim content is through .text.

```
<div class="portfolio-works-container"><!--portfolio-works-container-->
    <div class="portfolio-text">
         <h2>Hybrid Designs</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales id risus convallis aliquet. Sed eget felis risus. 
            Nullam nec nisi a tellus suscipit porta. Praesent odio lectus, lobortis vel iaculis eu, dignissim id quam. 
            Vestibulum non iaculis leo. Ut nec mi vitae magna aliquam consequat. Nam eget gravida nunc. 
            In eu sem dictum, pretium nisl ut, imperdiet risus. Sed pellentesque tincidunt ligula eget convallis. 
            Curabitur et odio elit. Aliquam at lacus vitae est iaculis pellentesque. Duis dignissim lobortis metus id malesuada. 
            Sed tincidunt molestie arcu, quis sollicitudin lacus laoreet ac. 
            Sed non augue magna. Quisque blandit vestibulum arcu sit amet suscipit.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-img">
        <a href="#.html"><img src="graphics/hybrid-screenshoot.jpg" width="327" height="119"></a> 
    </div>

</div><!--/portfolio-works-container-->

$(function() {

    /* check all columns */
    $('.portfolio-img').each(function(){
        if ($.trim( $(this).val() ).length === 0) {
            $(this).hide();
             $(".portfolio-text").css('width','100%');
        }
    });

});
```

I have uploaded it onto jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sf8aH/2/

Comment: By trim you mean crop?

Comment: What is this " The only way I know how to trim content is through text."?

Comment: the idea is when there isn't an image it will remove it and expand the other div. So trim means remove, when an image is present.

Comment: you can use [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: by this "when there isn't an image" do you mean the img tag's src attribute is blank..?

Comment: I would like to figure out how to remove the image using jquery. Normally when i want to remove text when it is not present to expand another div i use the .text function but because the image isn't text the code is not working and not detecting the image.